# How to match pattern with regex in PosgreSQL?

Tags: regex, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL I have two kinds of records in my column: 
 `ABCD-XYZE12-G56` and `ABCD-XYZE-G56`.

In both I want to ged rid of `G56` and select each one separately.

So my query to find (BCD-XYZE12) is:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(string, '[A-Z]+-[A-Z0-9]+') from table;
```

But it matches also: `ABCD-XYZE`.

Comment: You want `regexp_replace()` not `substring()`. `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(string, 'G56', '') FROM table;`

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^[A-Z]+-(?=[A-Z0-9]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]+` to return records of Type: ABCD-XYZE12

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zfDS0d/1)

Comment: For the second case, I tried `'^[A-Z]+-[\w]+[-]'` but I got everything.

Comment: change `\w` to `[A-Z]`

Answer (score 0):

To remove a particular portion of a string I'd suggest using `regexp_replace()`. To match on a string after applying `regexp_replace()` you can used the `~` operator in the `WHERE` clause.

The `~` operator is a POSIX regex match operator. PostgreSQL documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE).

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(string, '-G56', '') str
    FROM test
) t
WHERE t.str ~ 'BCD-XYZE12'
;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5a15b/6) to see some working examples.